# How to overlay logo in all edges in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Am using this command to render logo to all edges, starting from left upper edge

```
ffmpeg -i film.mp4 -i logo_white.png -filter_complex   "[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between=(t,0,360)':x=0+t*60:y=t[out]" -map "[out]" output2.mp4
```

but after 30 seconds the logo gose beyond the width. How to make it move around all edges? Should i use if statments and do the calculation? or is there any easier way?

**UPDATE:**

I want to make the logo float from the first edge to all other edges without stopping while the Video is running

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would this be as expected? https://i.ibb.co/ryhB2CG/I-Love-Cats.gif

Comment: @RicardoBohner Yessss i was looking for something like this all the day. Can you please submit your answer?

Comment: With logo you actually mean an image right? Cause I used drawtext to do this....I rewrite the code and  send it later, are you on windows?

Comment: @RicardoBohner 1) Yes i mean image. 2) No am on Ubuntu (using the command line). Many thanks to you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's say you would like 1 full circle to take 20 seconds, 5 seconds from 1 corner to the other:

**For an animated image:**

```
ffmpeg -t 20 -loop 1 -i "I love cats.png" -i logo.png -loop 0 -filter_complex ^
"[0][1]overlay=x='0+(t-0)*(W-w)/5':y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[img]; ^
[img][1]overlay=x=W-w:y='0+(t-5)*(H-h)/5':enable='between(t,5,10)'[img]; ^
[img][1]overlay=x=(W-w)-(t-10)*(W-w)/5:y=H-h:enable='between(t,10,15)'[img], ^
[img][1]overlay=x=0:y=(H-h)-(t-15)*(H-h)/5:enable='between(t,15,20)'" -c:v libwebp_anim -compression_level 5 "Output.webp"
```

Oneliner:

```
ffmpeg -t 20 -loop 1 -i "I love cats.png" -i logo.png -loop 0 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x='0+(t-0)*(W-w)/5':y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[img];[img][1]overlay=x=W-w:y='0+(t-5)*(H-h)/5':enable='between(t,5,10)'[img];[img][1]overlay=x=(W-w)-(t-10)*(W-w)/5:y=H-h:enable='between(t,10,15)'[img],[img][1]overlay=x=0:y=(H-h)-(t-15)*(H-h)/5:enable='between(t,15,20)'" -c:v libwebp_anim -compression_level 5 "Output.webp"
```

I used webp because it gives smaller output than gif or animated png and allows looping but you also can use something else...

[Cat with logo](https://i.ibb.co/SXPcsDf/output.webp)

**For a movie:**

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i "logo.png" -filter_complex ^
"[0][1]overlay=y=0:x='mod=(t*((W-w)/5),W-w)':enable='lt(mod(t,20),5)'[vid]; ^
[vid][1]overlay=x=W-w:y='mod=(t*((H-h)/5),H-h)':enable='lt(mod(t-5,20),5)'[vid]; ^
[vid][1]overlay=y=H-h:x='(W-w)-(mod(t*((W-w)/5),W-w))':enable='lt(mod(t-10,20),5)'[vid]; ^
[vid][1]overlay=x=0:y='(H-h)-(mod(t*((H-h)/5),H-h))':enable='lt(mod(t-15,20),5)'[vid]" -map [vid] -map 0:a:0 -vsync 0 -c:v libx264 "output.mp4"
```

Oneliner:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=y=0:x='mod=(t*((W-w)/5),W-w)':enable='lt(mod(t,20),5)'[vid];[vid][1]overlay=x=W-w:y='mod=(t*((H-h)/5),H-h)':enable='lt(mod(t-5,20),5)'[vid];[vid][1]overlay=y=H-h:x='(W-w)-(mod(t*((W-w)/5),W-w))':enable='lt(mod(t-10,20),5)'[vid];[vid][1]overlay=x=0:y='(H-h)-(mod(t*((H-h)/5),H-h))':enable='lt(mod(t-15,20),5)'[vid]" -map [vid] -map 0:a:0 -vsync 0 -c:v libx264 "output.mp4"
```

Comment: Can this work for a video? i will post my command in another comment. it says that option loop not found

Comment: ffmpeg -t 20 -loop 1 -i film.mp4 -i logo_white.png -loop 0 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x='0+(t-0)*(W-w)/5':y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[img];[img][1]overlay=x=W-w:y='0+(t-5)*(H-h)/5':enable='between(t,5,10)'[img];[img][1]overlay=x=(W-w)-(t-10)*(W-w)/5:y=H-h:enable='between(t,10,15)'[img],[img][1]overlay=x=0:y=(H-h)-(t-15)*(H-h)/5:enable='between(t,15,20)'"  output2.mp4

Comment: I also used this :  ffmpeg -t 20 -stream_loop 1 -i film.mp4 -i logo_white.png -loop 0 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x='0+(t-0)*(W-w)/5':y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[img];[img][1]overlay=x=W-w:y='0+(t-5)*(H-h)/5':enable='between(t,5,10)'[img];[img][1]overlay=x=(W-w)-(t-10)*(W-w)/5:y=H-h:enable='between(t,10,15)'[img],[img][1]overlay=x=0:y=(H-h)-(t-15)*(H-h)/5:enable='between(t,15,20)'"  output.mp4

But the video stops at 20 seconds

Comment: I guess yes, the part with the coordinates should be the same only the main command changes, I'll try it with a video

Comment: @Мохамед Русланович I added the part on how to do this with a movie to the answer...

Comment: Many thanks to you

Comment: You are welcome